# Java and "Type Safety..."

Tags: java, typesafe

I have a quick question about type safety

I have this method and a class variable defined:

```
private List<SelectItem> listBait = null;


public List<SelectItem> getListBait() {
    // Cache to avoid resorting and rebuilding list numerous times
    if (null == listBait) {
        listBait = ConfigurationBean.getCurrentInstance().getMeta().getListBait();
    }
    return listBait;
}
```

Now, I get a warning on the assignment in the if. It says `Type safety: The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to List<SelectItem>`.

First the getCurrentInstance method in ConfigurationBean is:

```
public static ConfigurationBean getCurrentInstance() {
    // This is a neat way to get a handle on the instance of this bean in the application scope from other Java code...
    FacesContext context = Util.getFacesContext();
    ConfigurationBean bean = (ConfigurationBean) context.getApplication().getVariableResolver().resolveVariable(context, "Configuration");
    return bean;
}
```

... and the getMeta method (and instance variable) is:

```
private final MetaDataBean meta = new MetaDataBean();

public MetaDataBean getMeta() {
    return meta;
}
```

The getListBait() method from the MetaDataBean looks like this:

```
public List<SelectItem> getListBait() {
    List<SelectItem> options = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    for (Bait bait : getAllBaits()) {
        if (!bait.isInActive()) {
            options.add(new SelectItem(bait.getKey(), bait.getName()));
        }
    }
    return options;
}
```

So from what I understand it should not give the warning in question...? Anyone, who can explain this to me - the suggested solutions don't seem to solve the problem (apart from the @SuppressWarning ;-) ).

This is on Java 1.6.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**
... and going through this edit actually solved it!

What had happened was that probably some friendly advice from Eclipse "helped" me define the MetaDataBean like this:

```
public class MetaDataBean<whyFish> extends BaseBean implements Serializable {
:
:
```

... and that does not make sense. I can't tell when that little "" has been added to the declaration - but removing that made all the warnings disappear :-)

Thanks a lot!! - now I still trust a little in what Java I know so far ;-)

/John

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. There's too much we don't know here. Additionally, note that there's no need to use `if (null == ...)` in Java... the reasons for using it in some languages don't apply to Java (where an `if` condition has to be a `boolean` expression) and putting the variable first is more readable to most people.

Comment: Please check if `ConfigurationBean` or some of the return values are generic as well. Not providing generic parameters here might cause the compiler to deactivate them in the method call as well.

Comment: As @Thomas hints at, the problem is probably in `getCurrentInstance` or `getMeta` as well as the class declaration of their return types.

Comment: @Thomas - I have clarified that the getListBait() method is defined in the ConfigurationBean. How can I check that the bean itself is generic??

Comment: @JonSkeet - I have tried to isolate the problem to exactly the method showing the warning and the method it calls that returns the same type of data as expected in the calling method.

I didn't know I could just ask `if(!listBait)..` in Java - as I do in JavaScript. Thanks! The reason why I put `null` first is a pattern to avoid assigning the value by accident - and I think that is best practice ;-)

Comment: @JohnDalsgaard We are still just guessing. You should show us a complete program (reduce your program to only the parts that are necessary to reproduce the warning) or at least `getCurrentInstance`, `getMeta` and the class declarations if their return types.

Comment: @Radiodef - of course. And I just did - and found the problem! So you were so right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a raw type is the erasure of that type ([4.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8)), a raw `MetaDataBean` returns a raw `List` from `getListBait`.

The solution is either to remove the generic type parameter from `MetaDataBean` or to not use a raw type, depending on whether the parameter is actually necessary.

Answer (score 0):

As per the last edit. A generics had been added to one of the class definitions - probably by the friendly help of Eclipse (and obviously me accepting it without knowing exactly what I did!).

The excellent comments for further info helped find the wrong declaration :-)